# Error in running MapReduce job in eclipse from windows

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, windows, hadoop

I Have pseudo-distributed Hadoop setup on a linux machine. I have done a few examples in eclipse which is also installed in that linux machine and they worked fine. Now I want to perform MapReduce Jobs through eclipse (installed in windows machine) and access the HDFS which is already present in my linux machine. I have written the following Driver code:

```js
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class Windows_Driver extends Configured implements Tool{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  
  int exitcode = ToolRunner.run(new Windows_Driver(), args);
  System.exit(exitcode);
  
 }

 @Override
 public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
  
  JobConf conf = new JobConf(Windows_Driver.class);

  conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://<Ip address>:50070");

  FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path("sample"));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("sam"));
  

  conf.setMapperClass(Win_Mapper.class);
  

  conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  conf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

  conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

  JobClient.runJob(conf);
  
  
  return 0;

 }

}
```

And the Mapper code :

```js
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class Win_Mapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text,Text, Text> {

 @Override
 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> o, Reporter arg3) throws IOException {
  
  
        ...
  
  o.collect(... , ...);
 }

}
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```html
 SEVERE: PriviledgedActionException as:miracle cause:java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-miracle\mapred\staging\miracle1262421749\.staging to 0700
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-miracle\mapred\staging\miracle1262421749\.staging to 0700
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:691)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:664)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:514)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:349)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:193)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:126)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:942)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1353)
 at Windows_Driver.run(Windows_Driver.java:41)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
 at Windows_Driver.main(Windows_Driver.java:16)
```

How can I rectify the error? And how can I access my HDFS remotely from windows?

Answer (score 0):

submit() method on the Job creates an internal Jobsubmitter instance and that would do all the data validations including input path,output path availability,file/directory creation permissions and other things. During different phases of MR, it will create temporary directories under which it will put the temp. files. The temp directory is taken from `core-site.xml` with property `hadoop.tmp.dir`. The issue with your system is it seems the temp. directory is /tmp/ and the user running the MR job doesn't have permission to change its rwx status to 700. Provide appropriate permissions and rerun the job.